# How do I fix a memory leak cause by ContextMenuStrips not disposing

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks

I asked this question here ([How do I fix a memory leak caused by an object referenced by a ContextMenuStrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507587/how-do-i-fix-a-memory-leak-caused-by-an-object-referenced-by-a-contextmenustrip)) and thought it had been answered, but the obvious fix did not work. I have searched about the problem, and found many questions and blogs about memory leaks due to ContextMenuStrips, but found no concrete answers. I have created a small WinForms test application that exhibits the problem.  Upon creation of the project I add a TreeView to Form1 in the designer and modify Form1.cs as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeView1.NodeMouseClick += OnNodeMouseClick;

        var object1 = new MyObject("Object1");
        var object2 = new MyObject("Object2");
        var object3 = new MyObject("Object3");

        var treeNode1 = new TreeNode(object1.Name) { Tag = object1 };
        var treeNode2 = new TreeNode(object2.Name) { Tag = object2 };
        var treeNode3 = new TreeNode(object3.Name) { Tag = object3 };
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode1);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode2);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode3);
    }

    private void OnNodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode == null)
            return;

        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
            return;

        MyObject targetObject = (MyObject)e.Node.Tag;

        if (targetObject == null)
            return;

        var point = new Point(e.X + 20, e.Y);
        var popupMenu = targetObject.PopupMenu;
        popupMenu.Show(this, point);
    }
}
```

I also have the MyObject class:

```
class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ContextMenuStrip PopupMenu
    {
        get
        {
            ContextMenuStrip myPopup = new ContextMenuStrip();
            myPopup.Items.Add(ItemDelete);
            return myPopup;
        }
    }

    public ToolStripMenuItem ItemDelete
    {
        get
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem itemDelete = new ToolStripMenuItem("Delete " + Name);
            itemDelete.Click += ItemDelete_Click;
            return itemDelete;
        }
    }

    public void ItemDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

I have not implemented the delete method as it is not needed to see the problem. Whenever you right click on an object in the tree a new ContextMenuStrip is created. The menus never get deleted. In my actual application the context menus can reference some large objects. The retention path shown in dotMemory has the ContextMenuStrip referenced by a UserPreferenceChangeEventHandler. How can I dispose of the menus after they close?

Comment: Instead of creating a new `ContextMenuStrip` for each right click on a node, create one in the `Form` and change the `Text` property of the delete menu item when needed. Then dispose the `ContextMenuStrip` in the form's `Disposing(...)` method.

Comment: The form will only be disposed when the application is closed. I could have hundreds of ContextMenuStrips holding on to lots of memory hungry objects by then.

Comment: Create only one and reuse it.

Comment: When you manage Controls yourself, outside the Forms ownership, you'd better call Close() or Dispose() on them.

Comment: And, using a property to create new items this way is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Loathing. I can make use of that idea. I have many different objects with different menus, which is why each object creates its own menu. But I can check to see if the forms ContextMenuStrip is null and dispose if it, before resetting it to the new menu. I have implemented this in the real app, and I am down to one menu referencing one large object. Technically this is only a leak if I am trying to delete that object, but at least it will go away when I open a menu on another object.

Answer (score 1):

Change your OnNodeMouseClick to this:

```
    private void OnNodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode == null)
            return;
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
            return;
        MyObject targetObject = (MyObject)e.Node.Tag;
        if (targetObject == null)
            return;
        e.Node.ContextMenuStrip = MyObject.SharedPopup;
    }
```

And your MyObject class to this:

```
class MyObject
{
    private static ContextMenuStrip sharedPopup;
    public static ContextMenuStrip SharedPopup
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == sharedPopup)
            {
                sharedPopup = new ContextMenuStrip();
                ToolStripMenuItem deleteItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
                deleteItem.Click += ItemDelete_Click;
                deleteItem.Paint += deleteItem_Paint;
                sharedPopup.Items.Add(deleteItem);
            }
            return sharedPopup;
        }
    }

    static void deleteItem_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
        item.Text = "Delete " + ((item.Owner as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl as TreeView).SelectedNode.Text;
    }

    public MyObject(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    static void ItemDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

This reuses the same context menu and just updates the text when it needs to.

Comment: It is better to have the menu as an instance variable in a `Form` or other high level container control / panel. The problem with having it as a static variable is that the application becomes responsible for disposing it. E.g. you should add an `Application.Exit += ` and then dispose the object.

Comment: The memory will be released when the application exits regardless of if there is an Application Exit handler.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Because the memory is owned by the process. It is managed memory. When a managed process ends, all managed memory associated with it is released.  Only unmanaged resources leak if they are not explicitly freed.

Comment: `ContextMenuStrip` is a subclass of `ToolStrip` which looks like it allocates unmanaged resources in the source code. Regardless, it implements `IDisposable` and as such it should be disposed.

Comment: I just tested creating 1,000,000 ContextMenuStrips and adding them to a static List variable.  When I closed the application all of that memory was freed.  Disposing of memory is obviously very important.  But static variables will be cleaned properly by the runtime.  Give it a try yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: As far as I know, the runtime does not automatically dispose static references. What if the `ContextMenuStrip` contained images or other resources? It's better to call dispose than not. Anyway, I don't want to debate with someone over best practices. If you don't want to call dispose then don't.

Comment: The ContextMenuStrip's finalizers will clean up all of the unmanaged resources associated with it. Calling Dispose would help improve performance, but since this only occurs once while the process is closing performance is not a concern.  Adding the ContextMenuStrip as an instance variable means that Dispose would need to be called when the owning instance is destroyed. That just makes the code unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Adding a `winforms` control to a business object class as a static reference is a poor design. It's merging layers that should be kept separate. As for the "unnecessarily complex" rational of making it a static reference, well, if three lines of code is complex, then to each his own.

Comment: Loathing, I agree with you. I need to figure out how to come up with menus customized for each object type, but using an MVVM pattern. I would prefer not to have my data objects cluttered by code describing the UI. It is too late to fix this application, but a new one is in the works.

Answer (score 0):

I went with Loathing's suggestion but with a modification. My example was too simple and did not show all the different object types and all the different menu builds that can occur in the actual application. I needed a quick fix, and modifying the process of building the menus was not practical. I modified my handler as shown below and now there is only one ContextMenuStrip at a time. As a new one is created, the old one is deleted.

```
    private void OnNodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode == null)
            return;

        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
            return;

        MyObject targetObject = (MyObject)e.Node.Tag;

        if (targetObject == null)
            return;

        var point = new Point(e.X + 20, e.Y);
        var popupMenu = targetObject.PopupMenu;

        if (ContextMenuStrip != null)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip.Dispose();
        }

        ContextMenuStrip = popupMenu;
        ContextMenuStrip.Show(this, point);
    }
```

BTW, I did not develop this code. This part of the application is very old, and I only try to fix the really bad things like memory leaks.